# how to make nested iteration over spark dataset and drop element

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi i have a DataSet of Track.class i want to merge all tracks that are within same interval of time for example 5 min .i.e any tracks start after a track that ends within 5 min before will be the same track.its look like fusion task.

my input :

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  trackId |  start_time    |  end_time                  |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1       | 12:00:00       |   12:04:00                 |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  2       | 12:05:00       |   12:08:00                 |  
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  3       | 12:20:00       |   12:22:00                 | 
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

output :(trackId  : 1,2 are been merged since diff of start and end of each one is  within 5 min)

```
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  trackId |  start_time    |  end_time                  |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1       | 12:00:00       |  12:08:00                  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  3       | 12:20:00       |   12:22:00                 |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

so how  can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give your exact schema but essentially you want to use Spark's `window` function. something like

```
df.groupBy(window(df.col("time"),"50 seconds").agg(first("id").as("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

i can use the lead function to append a column hold the value of the next start time and then i subtract current end date and the next start date and that's it.

```
> dataset.withColumn("lead",lead(dataset.col(start_date),1).over(orderBy(start_date)));

+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  trackId |  start_time    |  end_time   |      lead    |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1       | 12:00:00       |   12:04:00  |     12:05:00 |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  2       | 12:05:00       |   12:08:00  |  12:20:00    |  
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  3       | 12:20:00       |   12:22:00  |     null     | 
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```